# Simplifying complex if statements

Tags: if-statement, optimization, coldfusion

I have a matrix of values that I need to check against to show different content on a page. The vars valueA and valueB each have at least 3 possible states. The code below works fine, but I am wondering if there is a better / smarter way to handle this. Thanks!

```
<cfif valueA EQ -1 AND valueB EQ -1>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA EQ -1 AND valueB EQ 0>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA EQ -1 AND valueB EQ 1>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA EQ -1 AND valueB GT 1>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA EQ 0 AND valueB EQ -1>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA EQ 0 AND valueB EQ 0>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA EQ 0 AND valueB EQ 1>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA EQ 0 AND valueB GT 1>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA EQ 1 AND valueB EQ -1>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA EQ 1 AND valueB EQ 0>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA EQ 1 AND valueB EQ 1>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA EQ 1 AND valueB GT 1>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA GT 1 AND valueB EQ -1>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA GT 1 AND valueB EQ 0>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA GT 1 AND valueB EQ 1>
    <!--- Do something --->
<cfelseif valueA GT 1 AND valueB GT 1>
    <!--- Do something --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: Look at Switch/Case.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a little cleaner perhaps. I could load all the values into a 2d array, and then use switch/case. Thanks!

Comment: A switch can only test for equals, so I can’t see how a switch will work in this example.

Comment: @Redtopia Correct, my apologies. I was thinking more along the lines of how SQL's `CASE/WHEN` works. If there are a bunch of cases to filter through, you may be able to do some math magic to speed it up. As far as I know, an `if/else` will filter through all of the combos until it finds a match, but a `switch/case`-type construct will short circuit and find the right match faster. If you can short circuit yourself, that would be the way to go. Alex's answer still uses an `if/elseif`, but it does the short circuit to skip a lot of the code. You also want to make your most-likely scenario first.

Comment: What does the "something" do? Calculate a value or something more complex? If it involves calculating a value and the comparisons are static, you might consider actual matrix table..

Answer (score 4):

The ColdFusion engine won't see complexity in the code above. The humans developers will have a bit of hard time (although I'm sure there are some who will have no problem to parse  that, (not me)).

Here is my version, which with the use of editor's code folding, it makes easier to read, at least for me.

```
<cfif valueA EQ -1>

    <cfif valueB EQ -1>
        <!--- Do something --->
    <cfelseif valueB EQ 0>
        <!--- Do something --->
    <cfelseif valueB EQ 1>
        <!--- Do something --->
    <cfelseif valueB GT 1>
        <!--- Do something --->
    </cfif>    

<cfelseif valueA EQ 0>

    <cfif valueB EQ -1>
        <!--- Do something --->
    <cfelseif valueB EQ 0>
        <!--- Do something --->
    <cfelseif valueB EQ 1>
        <!--- Do something --->
    <cfelseif valueB GT 1>
        <!--- Do something --->
    </cfif> 

<cfelseif valueA EQ 1>

    <cfif valueB EQ -1>
        <!--- Do something --->
    <cfelseif valueB EQ 0>
        <!--- Do something --->
    <cfelseif valueB EQ 1>
        <!--- Do something --->
    <cfelseif valueB GT 1>
        <!--- Do something --->
    </cfif> 

<cfelseif valueA GT 1>

    <cfif valueB EQ -1>
        <!--- Do something --->
    <cfelseif valueB EQ 0>
        <!--- Do something --->
    <cfelseif valueB EQ 1>
        <!--- Do something --->
    <cfelseif valueB GT 1>
        <!--- Do something --->
    </cfif> 

</cfif>
```

---

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is pretty much how I would write it. Another way to simplify this code would be to use cfscript syntax instead! Obviously this is more of a personal choice, but cfscript is really good these days. Personally, I prefer to use tag syntax only when I am outputting html, and then it comes in real handy. In fact, I love tag syntax for that!

Comment: Usually I prefer not to nest if/else statements because I find it less readable, but .. if the "Do something" code is more than a line or two, I'd agree this is a case where nesting makes the code *more* readable to humans.  That said, I'm curious what the code is actually doing and whether a different approach (than multiple conditionals) is an option here.  Hard hard to say without more info from the op though..

Comment: The "do something" is a variety of #navMenus# from <cfsavecontent> tags.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

To show you how the different options behave differently, I created a fiddle with the 2 `cfif` options so-far presented and added a `switch` option with a little bit of math magic to make a switch work.

The whole fiddle is at: https://trycf.com/gist/041d1a6c3b3701d30306a9c80f1ddbea/acf2018?theme=monokai

My `switch` code:

```
local.valA = arguments.valueA>1?99:arguments.valueA ; // If GT 1, then 99
local.valB = arguments.valueB>1?99:arguments.valueB ; // If GT 1, then 99

local.finalOut = "" ;

switch (valA*valB) { // multiply the two vals and it will be -1,0,1,99,-99 or -99*99
    case -1 : // One is -1 and One is 1 >> 1*-1=-1
        if (valA == 1) {
            finalOut = "1,-1" ;   
        } else {
            finalOut = "-1,1" ;
        }
        break ;
    case 1 : // Both are either 1 or -1  >> -1*-1=1 | 1*1=1
        if (valA == 1) {
            finalOut = "1,1" ;   
        } else {
            finalOut = "-1,-1" ;
        }
        break ;
    case 0 : // One is 0  >> 0*x=0
        if (valA == 0) {
            switch (valB) {
                case -1 : 
                    finalOut = "0,-1" ;
                    break;
                case 0 : 
                    finalOut = "0,0" ;
                    break;
                case 1 : 
                    finalOut = "0,1" ;
                    break;
                case 99 : 
                    finalOut = "0,99" ;
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            switch (valA) {
                case -1 : 
                    finalOut = "-1,0" ;
                    break;
                case 1 : 
                    finalOut = "1,0" ;
                    break;
                case 99 : 
                    finalOut = "99,0" ;
                    break;
            }
        }
        break ;
    default : // One > 1, Other not 0
        switch (ValA) {
            case -1 : // ValA is -1, ValB is >1
                finalOut = "-1,99" ;
                break ;
            case 1 : // ValA is 1, ValB is >1
               finalOut = "1,99" ;
                break ;
            case 99 : // ValA is >1, ValB <> 0
                switch (valB) {
                    case 1 :
                        finalOut = "99,1" ;
                        break ;
                    case -1 :
                        finalOut = "99,-1" ;
                        break ;
                    case 99 :
                        finalOut = "99,99" ;
                        break;
                }
                break ;
        }
        break ;
}
```

My Fiddle puts each of the 3 options in a function, so I could loop through them multiple times to demonstrate them and check timing. See the Fiddle above for those functions.

A couple of notes: as far as performance, you definitely want to try to short-circuit the logic as much as possible. Both my `switch` and Alex's `cfif` solutions were a bit faster than the original, un-nested `cfif`. That demonstrates the value of nesting the options to bypass some logic.

A `cfif` works from top to bottom. When I changed the array to add about 100K rows and mostly include values that would meet conditions early in the cycle without having to go through many options, all three options performed very similarly. If I included conditions that would fall at the end of the options, then the original `cfif` performed about a third slower than the other two options that short-circuited logic, with the `cfif` and the `switch` performing very similarly.

I tested with around 1M, 100K and 10K rows. With fewer rows, the performance was very close on all 3. I assume that's likely because of the variable instantiation and math checks being fairly consistent (despite number of iterations) and not being needed in the `cfif` versions.

One thing that I didn't test was tags vs script. I wrote my `switch` in script-syntax, and it will probably be slightly faster in tag-syntax. I also didn't test either of the `cfif`s in script. That might make a slight difference. Moving around the logic will also possibly change speed of the options.

**TL;DR:** Since I believe you said you will be using this to only evaluate one set of values, then Alex's solution will probably work best. I think you should go with what's easiest to read and interpret here. My example was mostly because you asked about performance. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I agree this is on the lower end of the readability spectrum, especially for the current application, but it may come in handy in the future.